# A Python library to convert text into character-level embedding and LSTM

Tags: python, lstm

I'm trying to recreate an experiment described in a paper where each character in a URL is converted to a 128-dimension embedding. My dataset looks like below.

[image]

I'm having trouble figuring out how to do the conversion process in Python. Can anyone suggest a library and function that will allow me to convert the domain column in my dataframe?

The paper describes the process in the diagram shown below.

[image]

*Bahnsen, Alejandro Correa, et al. "Classifying phishing URLs using recurrent neural networks." 2017 APWG symposium on electronic crime research (eCrime). IEEE, 2017.*

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing. Did you find a way to do this. If so please let me know the details.
Thanks
Matheesha